# The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have checked all similar questions on StackOverflow, but none of the answers solved my problem. I simply get the error in title.

Here is my MainVindow.xaml :

```
<Window x:Class="CodeFirstMVVM.App.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:cm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=System"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:CustomerOrder.App.ViewModel"
        xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=CustomerView}"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="500" Width="900">
    <Grid>
        <Canvas>
            <TextBox Height="23" Canvas.Left="131" TextWrapping="Wrap"  Canvas.Top="51" Width="283" Name="txtName" Text="{Binding NameUI}"/>
            <DataGrid x:Name="maingrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Entities, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEntity}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="265">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name" Width="200"></DataGridTextColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
            <DataGrid x:Name="ordergrid" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=maingrid, Path=SelectedItem.Orders}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" Canvas.Top="265" Canvas.Left="597">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Explanation}" Header="Orders" Width="200"></DataGridTextColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </Canvas>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And here is my App.xaml :

```
<Application x:Class="CustomerOrder.App.App" 
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
             xmlns:d ="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc ="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml" 
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Application.Resources>
        <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" d:IsDataSource="True" xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:CustomerOrder.App.ViewModel" />
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

On MainWindow.xaml.cs :

```
namespace CustomerOrder.App
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Can you tell me how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: post your `MainWindow.xaml.cs` code

Comment: the namespace is different, that's the problem `x:Class="CodeFirstMVVM.App.MainWindow"` and `namespace CustomerOrder.App`

Comment: @YuliamChandra that's the answer. You should post it as an answer and not as a comment.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To fix it, change the namespace of the xaml

```
<Window x:Class="CustomerOrder.App.MainWindow"
```

Answer (score 4):

I have gotten this error a number of times when all of the above checks were done and all the namespaces matched.

What fixed it, was simply retyping the "X:Class" attribute over again. Then VS seems to correctly parse it and make the proper association.

This technique of simply retyping what ever VS is complaining about works for a number of other errors as well.

Very frustrating...

Comment: I'm not sure why this was necessary, but this solution solved the problem for me as well.  The namespace was already correct in my case, and the software successfully compiled, but Visual Studio reported these errors anyway.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Your MainWindow class is not in the same namespace as the xaml .
Change it to

```
namespace CodeFirstMVVM.App
{ 
      /// <summary>
      /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml 
      /// </summary> 
      public partial class MainWindow : Window 
     { 
            public MainWindow()
            { 
                  InitializeComponent(); 
             }
     } 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

While Creating The xaml File The App.Xaml File Should have the class name as NameSpace.app, While Other Windows Should have NameSpace.WindowName.

Answer (score 0):

I had fiddled around with excluding and re-including xaml and corresponding files.

For me ***closing and reopening Visual Studio*** *worked*.